# $(X,f)$ is $minimal$ $\iff$ $X$ has no proper non-empty closed subset $Y $ which is $f-invariant$

Tags: real-analysis, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

> The topological dynamical system $(X,f)$ is $minimal$ if every orbit is dense in $X$. It is easily checked that $(X,f)$ is $minimal$ if and only $X$ has no proper non-empty closed subset $Y $ which is $f-invariant$

I read this from [here](https://www.math.uni-hamburg.de/home/geschke/papers/minimal.pdf), but it's not quite clear for me, can someone explain to me why is this true?
Note that: if $x\in X$, we define an orbit  of the system as $\mathcal O^+_f(x)=\big\{x,f(x),f\big(f(x)\big),\dots ,f^n(x),\dots \big\}$. 
We can also assume that $f$ is homomorphism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $(X,f)$ is minal and $C$ a non empty closed invariant subset. Let $x\in C$, $O_x=\{x,..,f^n(x),..\}\subset C$ implies that $\bar O_x$ the closure of $O_x$ is contained in $C$ and $\bar O_x$ is proper contradiction since $\bar O_x$ is invariant. (If $y=lim f^{i_n}(x), f(y)=lim f^{i_n+1}(x)$ since $f$ is continuous.)

Suppose that every proper closed subset is not invariant. $\bar O_x$ is closed and invariant, thus it is not proper.